# Fix tree-conflict caused by partial commit of Subversion svn move command

Tags: svn

I did some serious stupidity with `svn move` and `svn ci`.

Old directory structure:

```
source/branch1/test_framework/
source/branch2/test_framework/
```

Desired directory structure:

```
source/branch1/
source/branch2/
source/test_framework/ <-- This is a merge of the 2
```

Expected steps:

- Move source/branch1/test_framework/ to source/test_framework/
- Merge source/branch2/test_framework/ into source/test_framework/

How I started:

```
[dev@bld Prod1]$ svn move source/branch1/test_framework/ source/test_framework/
A         source/test_framework
D         source/branch1/test_framework/main.sh
D         source/branch1/test_framework
```

What I should have done:

```
[dev@bld Prod1]$ svn ci source/test_framework/ source/branch1/test_framework/ -m "Move test framework to top level."
```

**My Stupidity**:

```
[dev@bld Prod1]$ svn ci source/test_framework/ -m "Move test framework to top level."
Authentication realm: <http://localhost:8443> UNIX/LDAP User Account
Password for 'dev':
Adding         source/test_framework

Committed revision 274232.

[dev@bld Prod1]$ svn ci source/branch1/test_framework/ -m "Move test framework to top level."
Authentication realm: <http://localhost:8443> UNIX/LDAP User Account
Password for 'dev':
Deleting       source/branch1/test_framework
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Item '/repo/CoreApps/Prod1/source/branch1/test_framework' is out of date
```

Here, I looked up Google and StackOverflow and did the following fix suggested for the `Item ... out of date` error:

```
[dev@bld Prod1]$ svn update
Authentication realm: <http://localhost:8443> UNIX/LDAP User Account
Password for 'dev':
   C source/branch1/test_framework
At revision 274233.
Summary of conflicts:
  Tree conflicts: 1
```

Now I get stuck with this:

```
[dev@bld Prod1]$ svn ci source/branch1/test_framework/ -m "Move test framework to top level."
Authentication realm: <http://localhost:8443> UNIX/LDAP User Account
Password for 'dev':
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Aborting commit: '/repo/CoreApps/Prod1/source/branch1/test_framework' remains in tree-conflict
```

Now how do I fix this conflict? Please note that the `svn merge` is not an issue, and is instead just an explanation point of how I reached here.

I'd appreciate answers that give the reasoning on what to do as well.

**Edit** - The solution I used to fix my issue (*This is not ideal. The accepted answer is better*):

- `svn status source/branch1/test_framework/` to list the files deleted during the `svn move`
- `svn revert source/branch1/test_framework/$FILE` for each file listed above to undo the removal/deletion action of the `svn move`
- `svn delete source/test_framework/` to undo the copy action of the `svn move` followed by `svn ci source/test_framework/` to check-in the deletion.
- Do it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. checkout a fresh working copy, undo the bad revision (svn merge -c-274232 .), commit
2. do it right from scratch

This is a sort of undo/redo functionality in Subversion, a generic way of sorting out the messy state of the repository caused by a bad commit, when not many commits are done on the top and the messy commit does not have much intellectual work in it (which is exactly your case, commit is a simple `svn mv`). So basically I suggest to blindly roll back the change without even trying to understand the messy state (and save time) and then repeating `svn mv` correctly.

Comment: I fixed it another way. So the explanation please, if I am to accept this.

Comment: This is a sort of undo/redo in subversion, a generic way of sorting out the messy state of the repository caused by a bad commit, when not many commits are done on the top and the messy commit doe not have much intellectual work in it (which is exactly your case, commit is a simple _svn mv_). So I suggested to blindly roll back the change without even trying to understand the messy state (and save time) and then repeating svn mv correctly.

Comment: Add this into the answer and you have an accept(I'll add my solution into your answer as well).